# Create one more peer node using hyperledger-composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I implemented hyperledger composer tutorial and create a simple business network definition and deploy it on through composer and implement it's rest API's through composer-rest-server. Now I want to add one more peer to it on a different local machine which can access blockchain I created previously, so my question is How can I achieve that a different peer node (another local machine) connected to blockchain I created in the composer tutorial?

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46371470/how-to-add-a-new-peer-to-an-existing-hyperledger-fabric-network

Answer (score 0):

you can check the S/Overflow link provided by Ahmed Nasser relating to adding your peer to an existing Fabric network.

Once you have your Fabric network up and running, and all of your network configuration / resolution / docker configuration tested and working, you can come to Composer to define the connection info, such as adding additional peers (and therefore create the requisite business network cards that contain that info).

This single organisation tutorial can give you an idea of what's involved - it builds upon a Fabric network that was already created (a simple, one-peer Fabric blockchain Dev environment) ..see here ->  https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-single-org.html

It obviously refers to 'localhost' in this scenario - obviously, you are creating something on an IP network, so you will need IP addresses/ host resolution as appropriate.