# How to add a new peer to an existing Hyperledger Fabric network?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

When you create a hyperledger fabric network, you define organizations, orderers and peers in `crypto-config.yaml` and `configtx.yaml`.

But how do you add a new organization or a new peer to an existing organization in a network that is already setup? Run `cryptogen` and `configtxgen` pointing to config files that contain only the new organizations/peers? Re-generate everything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by generating the crypto material (using `cryptogen extends`) for the new peer, spawning the new peer and joining that peer to the existing channel on the network to sync-up.

You can find the complete guide at

[Extending Hyperledger Fabric Network: Adding a new peer](https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/extending-hyperledger-fabric-network-adding-a-new-peer-4f52f70a7217)

Comment: When I asked the question, `cryptogen` 1.0 had no `extends` subcommand, but now it is really the way to go! Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 9):

The whole point of using `cryptogen` is to help user to settle the crypto material for peer and organizations defined in the `crypto-config.yaml` file. However one can simply leverage `openssl` to generate keys and certificates of organization root CA, next generate user certificates and arrange them into the folder similar to what `cryptogen` is producing and startup your network. Therefore adding a new peer will stand up to simply generating a new set of keys and certificate signed by the root CA. Finally you can simply start new peer and join it to the channel by providing genesis block, which could be fetched from ordering service.

Now, the `configtxgen` tool helps you to configure your Hyperledger Fabric network it terms of which organizations will form a consortium and will have rights to join the channel. Extending this configuration is a bit more involved process than simply adding a new peer, in order to complete you will have to leverage the `configtxlator` tool, more details and example of how to use it you can find in the following [tutorial](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/examples/configtxupdate/README.md). In high level, you will have to read current channel configuration, parse it into the json format, update with new participants, compute the delta and generate configuration update transaction and the last step is to submit the update to the ordering service so it will take effect. Once you will accomplished config update you will be able to add new peers from new organization to the channel.